# Blender slow even on low poly model after adding armature

Tags: modeling

I created a model with multi-res modifiers, baked normals, and then removed all my multi-res modifiers leaving me with a low poly model of a human figure. Then I added a rigify armature, and now it's running very slow.

To click on any of the bones, it takes about 11 seconds to register the click and highlight the bone. It ran ok until I added the armature. I had my husband open it on his computer, and it runs MUCH better on his computer.

I'm running an 10th gen i7 with 32GB of Ram, and I have no other programs open. My husband is running a nothing-special 4 year old gaming PC with 8GB of Ram. The only advantage I can see that his computer has over mine is that mine is a laptop so only has the on-board intel graphics chip. But that shouldn't matter because it's not using the GPU while just modeling, right?

My question is - why is it so slow and how can I make it faster ? Thanks!
[image: text]

Comment: Blender isn't using GPU while modeling but is using for updating the viewport and UI generally. However if that was the case it would hang even before when you were working with Multires and baking and looks like it didn't. Then try to disable Armature modifiers, try to open Blender from command line with --debug parameter and see if any errors pop up there when you try doing the same, try updating Blender.

Comment: Updating Blender seems to have fixed the issue. I was using Blender 2.90. I upgraded it to 2.91 and it seems to be working fine now. Thanks!